# Design choice interactive chart ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Which is the best design choice to visualize interactive information in a ASP.NET MVC project with Razor view engine? 
In example, an interactive chart binded to the database with animations and cool graphic.
Could Flash together with actionscript3 be a good alternative?

Comment: I can provide an example. http://wheredoesmymoneygo.org/dashboard/#year=2008&focus=TOTAL&view=uk-bubble-chart. Would be a good approach to create something like that in flash with actionscript and then "feeding" some data, i.e. an XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of technologies you could use for this:

- Flash / Actionscript
- Flex (charting components might not be free)
- Silverlight
- HTML5 Canvas
- SVG
- etc.

They all have drawbacks (requiring plugins, or in the case of HTML5, not having great browser support), but the best option is probably the one that matches your skills best. If you've years of experience in Flash, it doesn't make sense to use one of the others - you'll just end up creating something less satisfactory at a slower pace.